# Accessing 2 different tables from same controller file

Tags: php, mysql, module, zend-framework2, tablegateway

I have successfully completed the the album table tutorial in Zend Framework 2 manual. I have implemented using tablegateway. I can see that he used only one table named "album" and hence he implemented according to that one table.

Lets say I have another table called "artist" that holds the information of each artists from that "album" table.

Now in manual, he simply uses:

```
$this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll();
```

Now I want to do similar thing with "artists" table so that my query can be like:

```
$this->getArtistsTable()->fetchAll();
```

So what should I change or add?? I already have created the artist table in mySql with columns: Name, DOB, Country.

P.S: I am not going to use joins or anything atm. Just want to access the second table in same controller (same module).

**SOLUTION:**
With the help of Venca, I was able to solve this problem: here is how you should edit the factory setting for 2 tables and more.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    // Given in Manual
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
             },
             'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                  $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                  $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                  $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                  return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
              },

          // Added another table named Artist
              'Album\Model\ArtistTable' =>  function($sm) {
                     $tableGateway = $sm->get('ArtistTableGateway');
                     $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                     return $table;
               },
               'ArtistTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                     $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                     $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                     $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Artist());
                     return new TableGateway('artist', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
             ),
         ); 
     }
```

Now you can access both tables from your controller. Problem Solved. Day well spent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html)

1. Create model
2. Create model table
3. Add factory to your module

   ```
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Album\Model\ArtistTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('ArtistTableGateway');
                $table = new ArtistTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'ArtistTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Artist());
                return new TableGateway('artist', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ),
    );
   ```

Comment: Can you please help me on the 3rd step. I already have the factory in module.php as done by the manual. Now that I want to involve another table into it, should I add the new settings in new factories? or add them in the existing one.

Comment: If you really have two minutes can you please do the following: edit the getServiceConfig() function for 2 tables. One is already given in the manual, you know for the album table, all I request you to do is add, in the same function the lines for a table named artist. I am only confused because the Module name and the table name are same. So hard to know what that function is doing.

Comment: Thats right here http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable

Comment: This function has settings for Table = Album. I want to know how you will add the setting in this very same function for another Table = Artist. That's all my confusion.

Comment: Where did you put the table settings for album ?? Anways I came up with solution. Check my code. Is that what you were trying to tell me?

Comment: I suggested you will add your album factories yourself :)

Comment: Anyway best practice is to inject dependecies to your controller via factory and not to pull them from service locator in controller directly. http://www.zfdaily.com/2012/07/getting-dependencies-into-zf2-controllers/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely go through that.